# What is the most efficient (fastest) way to find an N number of the largest integers in an array in C?

Tags: c, performance

Let's have an array of size 8
Let's have N be 3

With an array:
1 3 2 17 19 23 0 2

Our output should be:
23, 19, 17

Explanation: The three largest numbers from the array, listed in descending order.

I have tried this:

```
int array[8];
int largest[N] = {0, 0, 0};

for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE_OF_ARRAY; j++) {
        if (largest[i] > array[j]) {
            largest[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, let the constraint be as such:

> integers in the array should be 0 <= i <= 1 000
>
> N should be 1 <= N <= SIZE_OF_ARRAY - 1
>
> SIZE_OF_ARRAY should be 2 <= SIZE_OF_ARRAY <= 1 000 000

My way of implementing it is very inefficient, as it scrubs the entire array an N number of times. With huge arrays, this can take several minutes to do.

What would be the fastest and most efficient way to implement this in C?

Comment: You can find the three largest values with a single pass, although the question does not state what to do with duplicates.

Comment: @peepeepoopoo It is unclear whether duplicated maximum numbers are counted.

Comment: For an array of size 1000000, and N = 10000, the fastest method is to create a histogram of the array elements. Since it's given that the array elements are between 0 and 1000, the histogram size would be 1001. Running time: `O(array size)`.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Duplicate integers are also counted. The output can have duplicate integers, or even be an N number of the same integer, if the input array dictates it

Comment: Some bugs: (1) When you compare `if (largest[i] > array[j])`, don't you mean the opposite? Your code will find the N smallest array elements.
(2) Your `for` loop through `largest` starts at 1; it should start at 0.

Comment: @Howlium: Note the constraints listed after the code. The numbers are all between 0 and 1000. They can't be negative.

Comment: Good point; I've edited my comment.

Comment: It should be the selection algorithm, wiki it.

Comment: The [Quick Select](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) algorithm will partition the array to find the Nth highest (or lowest) value; all the values after (before) that will be larger (smaller).  It does so without doing a full sort on the array, which appears to be sufficient for your purposes.  I think that is what @perreal is suggesting, but I'm not sure why 'wiki it' is an appropriate direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way is to recognize that data doesn't just appear (it either exists at compile time; or arrives by IO - from files, from network, etc); and therefore you can find the 3 highest values when the data is created (at compile time; or when you're parsing and sanity checking and then storing data received by IO - from files, from network, etc). This is likely to be the fastest possible way (because you're either doing nothing at run-time, or avoiding the need to look at all the data a second time).

However; in this case, if the data is modified after it was created then you'd need to update the "3 highest values" at the same time as the data is modified; which is easy if a lower value is replaced by a higher value (you just check if the new value becomes one of the 3 highest values) but involves a search if a "previously highest" value is being replaced with a lower value.

If you need to search; then it can be done with a single loop, like:

```
    firstHighest = INT_MIN;
    secondHighest = INT_MIN;
    thirdHighest = INT_MIN;

    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        if(array[i] > thirdHighest) {
            if(array[i] > secondHighest) {
                if(array[i] > firstHighest) {
                    thirdHighest = secondHighest;
                    secondHighest = firstHighest;
                    firstHighest = array[i];
                } else {
                    thirdHighest = secondHighest;
                    secondHighest = array[i];
                }
            } else {
                thirdHighest = array[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

Note: The exact code will depend on what you want to do with duplicates (you may need to replace `if(array[j] > secondHighest) {` with `if(array[j] >= secondHighest) {` and `if(array[j] > firstHighest) {` with `if(array[j] >= firstHighest) {` if you want the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4 to give the answer 4, 4, 4 instead of 2, 3, 4).

For large amounts of data it can be accelerated with SIMD and/or multiple threads. For example; if SIMD can do "bundles of 8 integers" and you have 4 CPUs (and 4 threads); then you can split it into quarters then treat each quarter as columns of 8 elements; find the highest 3 values in each column in each quarter; then determine the highest 3 values from the "highest 3 values in each column in each quarter". In this case you will probably want to add padding (dummy values set to `INT_MIN`) to the end of the array to ensure that the array's total size is a multiple of SIMD width and number of CPUs.

For small amounts of data the extra overhead of setting up SIMD and/or coordinating multiple threads is going to cost more than it saves; and the "simple loop" version is likely to be as fast as it gets.

For unknown/variable amounts of data you could provide multiple alternatives (simple loop, SIMD with single thread, and SIMD with a variable number of threads) and decide which method to use (and how many threads to use) at run-time based on the amount of data.

Comment: Wow, this answer is way above and beyond. Thank you for taking the time to inform about this, it has been very heplful!

Comment: Frankly, I am surprised that this answer was accepted. It certainly doesn't scale to the original requirements. There is a superior answer by @Howlium below.

Comment: @VladFeinstein: The histogram approach is a horrible performance disaster because you're repeatedly accessing/modifying an "occurrences" table in ways that can not scale easily (to multiple CPUs or SIMD), while also pounding the daylights out of the cache with "likely worst possible" access patterns, to generate a pile of information that you simply don't need in the first place.

Comment: @Brendan - that may be (not cache friendly), but it has linear complexity, while yours is quadratic (when N is close to the size of that array).

Comment: @VladFeinstein: N is constant, and N is 3. If N is close to the size of the array then the array has 3 elements (so small that performance is irrelevant). My approach is "O(M)" (where `M` is the length of the array). Your approach is also "O(M)", but your "O" is an order of magnitude worse.

Comment: @VladFeinstein: Note that for N=1, 2, 3, 4 you can have multiple different/separate versions of the code and all versions will be "O(M) with smaller O than yours". This continues up until N becomes "about half of the registers the CPU has" (e.g. up until N=8 for 64-bit code using AVX2).

Comment: @Brendan - `3` was just an example, please see `constraint` in the question: `N should be 1 <= N <= SIZE_OF_ARRAY - 1`

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the histogram algorithm. Since the values have to be between 0 and 1000, you just allocate an array for each of those values:

```
#define MAX_VALUE 1000
int occurrences[MAX_VALUE+1];
int largest[N];
int i, j;

for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    largest[N] = -1;

for (i=0; i<=MAX_VALUE; i++)
    occurrences[i] = 0;

for (i=0; i<SIZE_OF_ARRAY; i++)
    occurrences[array[i]]++;

// Step through the occurrences array backward to find the N largest values.
for (i=MAX_VALUE, j=0, i; i>=0 && j<N; i--)
    if (occurrences[i] > 0)
        largest[j++] = i;
```

Note that this will yield only one element in `largest` for each unique value. Modify the insertion accordingly if you want all occurrences to appear in `largest`. Because of that, you may get values of -1 for some elements if there weren't enough unique large numbers to fill the `largest` array. Finally, the results in `largest` will be sorted from largest to smallest. That will be easy to fix if you want to: just fill the `largest` array from right to left.

Comment: Looks like this will miss duplicates, though that could be corrected with a minor tweak.

Comment: Right. I noted that in my answer. The question is unclear about how to handle duplicates. And you’re right that it’s trivial to track the multiples: the count is the value of each `occurrences` array element.

Comment: To handle an array of N integers it's likely that your "`occurrences[MAX_VALUE+1]`" will need to handle negative numbers, and likely that it will need to consume 16 GiB of memory. For large arrays you'll probably spend so much time transferring data to/from swap space that the user dies of old age before your code finishes.

Comment: The range stated in the problem is 0..1000.

Answer (score 1):

One method I can think of is to just sort the array and return the first N numbers. Since the array is sorted, the N number we return will be the N largest numbers of the array. This method will take a time complexity of `O(nlogn)` where `n` is the number of elements we have in the given array. I think this is probably very good time complexity you can get when approaching this problem.

Another approach with similar time complexity would be to use a `max-heap`. Form max-heap from the given array and for `N` times, use `pop()` (or extract or whatever you call it) to get the top-most element which would be the max element remaining in the heap after each `pop`.

The time complexity of this approach could be considered to be even better than first one - `O(n + Nlogn)` where `n` is the number of elements in array and N is the number of largest elements to be found. Here, `O(n)` would be required to build heap and for popping the top-most element, we would need `O(logn)` for N times which sums up to - `O(n + Nlogn)`, slightly better than `O(nlogn)`

Comment: Not the fastest, since the histogram method requires O(N)